# First character disappears when piping script with ffmpeg to bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I often create bash scripts with bash and pipe the results to bash... When I do this:

```bash
echo -e "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 1 -f null /dev/null\necho foo"|bash
```

I get

```
bash: line 2: cho: command not found
```

Where did the 'e' of 'echo' go? What does ffmpeg do there? Other commands work fine.

Note also:

```bash
echo -e "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 1 -f null /dev/null\necho foo" > /tmp/foo.sh
bash /tmp/foo.sh #works
bash < /tmp/foo.sh #doesn't
```

Comment: Show output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: @Cyrus 4.4.12(1)-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` also reads from standard input, which it inherits from its parent process, which is the `bash` process reading your command line. This means `ffmpeg` is reading the `e` from `echo` following the new line.

One fix is to redirection standard input for `ffmpeg`:

```
echo -e "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 1 -f null /dev/null < /dev/null \necho foo"|bash
```

However, I can't help but point out that there isn't really any reason to run a script like this. If you want it in a separate process, start a subshell:

```
(
  ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f lavfi -i nullsrc -t 1 -f null /dev/null
  echo foo
)
```

Comment: I can't help but add... the reason until now was convenience - it helps me to build&debug single-purpose, never-revisit scripts quickly. And it worked hundreds of times, until now ;)